# How to determine what a PHP page posts back to an AJAX call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've used ajax quite a bit to send data off to a php page and get something back, but I'm not sure how to determine *what* specifically gets sent back.  I understand what most of the fields here do, but I have a few questions as well.

My current code looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
              url: "search.php", 
              type: "post",
              dataType: "json",
              data: {partNumber: q , newType:newType},
              success: function(data) {
                  console.log(data);
              }
          });
```

One thing I don't fully understand is how the `success:` line works.  When I say `success: function(data)`, it's my understanding that I'm saying "upon success (*of something? I'm not sure what*), the information that is returned to this ajax function will be called `data`," and then inside the brackets, I'm choosing to `console.log` that `data`.

Please correct me if I'm wrong in that assumption.

Ultimately, my php page will do a ton of work and return an array with data in it.  If the last line of my php code is:

```
$myArray = array("bob","dan","carl","mike");
```

how do I choose for *that* to be returned to ajax?  The php page is working fine, but right now my `console.log(data)` line of code is not returning anything.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ explains it quite well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Your on "success" is basically saying when there is not an error that occurs.

Here is testing error

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'search.php',
  success: function(){
    alert('success');
  },
  error: function(){
    alert('failure');
  }
});
```

2) For your "data" what you echo on the php side gets returned into the variable defined in your

```
function(results) {
```

for example if you want to return an array you may want to return "echo" json

your array should include a key and a value

```
$myArray = array("key" => "value");

echo json_encode($myArray);
```

and on the jquery side parse the json object returned.

```
function(data) {
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

    alert(obj.key);
```

3) Pass JSON Objects

```
var JSONObject= {"partNumber":q, "newType":newType};
var jsonData = JSON.parse( JSONObject );  

var request = $.ajax({
  url: "search.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: jsonData,
  dataType: "json"
});
```

Comment: I've modified my php page to read `echo json_encode($i);`, and if I look in my developer tools, the correct output is there, but my `console.log(data);` still shows nothing.  Can you think of what that might be?

Comment: @JohnWu you need to parse out the data returned otherwise it probably return only an object

Comment: this is a great post.  Thank you for explaining it so well.

Answer (score 4):

You are not supposed to `return` anything from the php page called by your ajax, you're supposed to `echo` it (i.e. write it to the response).

```
echo json_encode($myArray);
```

And if what you're echoing is not JSon, then take out `dataType: "json"`.  The `success` function means that the request was successful, i.e. a response was received back from the server with status 200.  There is also an `error` method you can use for when you don't get a successful response back.

```
          success: function(data) {
              console.log(data);
          },
          error: function(data) {
              console.log("Error: "+data);
          }
```

Comment: yup, so I understand that `success` is derived from the status code of the page - maybe I wasn't clear in that I wasn't sure WHAT specifically on that page got sent back when the success function runs.  Right now I have `echo $i`, but I guess I need to json_encode that.  Let me try that and see if it works.  So is what's returned to the ajax call whatever is ECHOED?

Comment: the whole page 'oiutput' is sent back, but if its not in the expected format the function will not handle the data as desired. this is why you tell the function what the format will be

Comment: @JohnWu Whatever is written to the response. So whatever is echoed, but also any HTML that you may have outside PHP blocks like `<html><head>` etc. So if you intend to return JSON, take that stuff out.

Comment: okay - I took out `dataType: json` and modified the php not to `json_encode` and it works fine now - @Dagon - thank you!  This is the ultimate question I was having a hard time with, so the whole page gets sent back, but since I specify `dataType: 'json'`, only things that are json encoded will be handled?

Comment: firebug for firefox is great for debugging this sort of thing, it will show you the data that is being returned to your Ajax function. you should only output what you need\want if you want json encoded data just return that, not that and some html to.